# Using variable in table

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to move certain configs values into variables to make my file more maintainable by doing this ( note only pasting relevant code)

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
   var dir = {
        root : process.cwd() + '/test/e2e/stories/',
        all : dir.root + '**/*.js ',
        safari : dir.root + 'safari/**/*.js'
    };
};
```

However it is unable to read dir.root. If i change it to

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
   var root = process.cwd() + '/test/e2e/stories/';
   var dir = {

        all : root + '**/*.js ',
        safari : root + 'safari/**/*.js'
    };
};
```

then the root value is read fine. I was wondering if there is a way to read the value within 'dir' object

Comment: Can you paste in an sample of your "hushtable"?

Comment: I meant the 'dir' object.

Answer (score 2):

No not if you want to definite your hashmap all at once, but you could do this:

```
   var dir = {
        root : process.cwd() + '/test/e2e/stories/',
        all : '**/*.js ',
        safari : 'safari/**/*.js',
        path: function(place) { return this.root + place }
    };
```

and then access paths like:

```
dir.path('safari')
// returns /processcwd/test/e2e/stories/safari/**/*.js
```

alternatively you could definite your hashmap in parts:

```
var dir = { root: process.cwd() + '/test/e2e/stories/' };
dir.safari = dir.root + 'safari/**/*.js';
dir.all = dir.root + '**/*.js ';
```